# WebPart do not load a reference dll (RazorEngine.dll)

Tags: web-part, visual-studio, assembly-references

I have created a sp 2013 webpart. Inside this webpart I am using the RazorEngine.dll. It is included by NuGet and the solution builds. when I deploy and add the webpart to the page I got this error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'RazorEngine, Version=3.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9ee697374c7e744a' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'RazorEngine, Version=3.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9ee697374c7e744a' 
at MyCompany.SharePoint.WebParts.FormWebPart.Razor.RazorParser.GetRazorOutput(String template) 
at MyCompany.SharePoint.WebParts.FormWebPart.CONTROLTEMPLATES.FormUserControl.GetRazorOutput(String template, NameValueCollection data) 
at MyCompany.SharePoint.WebParts.FormWebPart.CONTROLTEMPLATES.FormUserControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
```

When I go to the assembly folder (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL) I do not see this dll. Why it is not deployed with my solution? I deployed the solution by VS.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because it is not deployed by your solution, only referenced!

In Visual Studio, double click the Package file and choose the "Advanced" tab.

Then on that tab add a reference to the file from where nuget downloads it in your project folder. This way it will be deployed to GAC on installation of your wsp